# Avoid multiple Case When - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
Select <CASE WHEN>, myfunction(param1, <CASE WHEN>)
FROM table
```

Both the Case When instances are the same set of conditions. So here I am clearly repeating the same conditions.

**Question:** Is there a way to not repeat the same Case When block efficiently?

Comment: Why do you think that a repeating  CASE _expression_ is inefficient?

Comment: no, no I didn't mean that. I was checking ways not to repeat without compromising efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use user defined Varaible

```
Select @res := CASE WHEN A = 1 then a END, myfunction(param1, @res)
FROM table1;
```

Or in mysql 8

```
WITH myselectanswer as
(Select  CASE WHEN A = 1 then a END myresult
FROM table1)
Select myselectanswer.myresult, myfunction(param1, myselectanswer.myresult)
FROM myselectanswer
```

Comment: That last one might actually compromise query performance if the actual query is more complex than the OP's contrived example.

Comment: @nbk When I use `:` insead of `:=` I get an error `truncated incorrect integer value`. I checked the documentation and didn't see any difference applicable in this scenario. Do you know what could be the problem here?

Comment: you can not use : it must be := so you set the user variable

Comment: @nbk sorry the comment have a mistake. Here is the original comment: When I use `=` insead of `:=` I get an error truncated incorrect integer value. I checked the documentation and didn't see any difference applicable in this scenario. Do you know what could be the problem here?

Comment: myql uses = for comparisons , so it try to find one, but it detects an error :=O is like an SET, which you use in stored procedures ot functions.